# Counting the number of strings preceded by other strings in R

Tags: r, string, count

I have a list of txt data files. Each of them is a record of all actions participants took in a set of tasks. An example piece of data for one task is:

```
[245] "2015-02-20 11:11:02|    134602| end of mat task (passed: 4/5)"                                                                                    
[246] "2015-02-20 11:11:02|    134599| step E9 abandoned - skipping to next"                                                                             
[247] "2015-02-20 11:11:01|    133596| step E9 bad choice - error limit reached"                                                                         
[248] "2015-02-20 11:10:47|    120007| intruder D started"                                                                                               
[249] "2015-02-20 11:10:47|    119792| step E9 bad choice"                                                                                               
[250] "2015-02-20 11:10:38|    110857| step E9 started"                                                                                                  
[251] "2015-02-20 11:10:37|    109844| step E1 success"                                                                                                  
[252] "2015-02-20 11:10:28|    101030| step E1 started"                                                                                                  
[253] "2015-02-20 11:10:27|    100018| step D10 success"                                                                                                 
[254] "2015-02-20 11:10:07|     79625| step D10 started"                                                                                                 
[255] "2015-02-20 11:10:06|     78609| step C12 success"                                                                                                 
[256] "2015-02-20 11:10:02|     74713| step C12 bad choice"                                                                                              
[257] "2015-02-20 11:09:50|     62673| step C12 started"                                                                                                 
[258] "2015-02-20 11:09:49|     61642| step B8 success"                                                                                                  
[259] "2015-02-20 11:09:47|     60003| intruder B started"                                                                                               
[260] "2015-02-20 11:09:33|     46047| step B8 started"                                                                                                  
[261] "2015-02-20 11:09:33|     46032| mats: B8,C12,D10,E1,E9"                                                                                           
[262] "2015-02-20 11:09:33|     46032| mat task: B8,C12,D10,E1,E9 displayed..."
```

Now, for each element of my list I need to count the number of times the "bad choice" message is displayed but only when it appears right after "success", so I need to count the number of instances a person made a mistake and successfully corrected it (the data is saved from bottom to the top, so newer events are above the older ones).

And secondly, there are some intruder tasks in the procedure that are randomly activated and it is possible that a message starting with "intruder..." (e.g. "intruder B started") might appear between a "bad choice" and "success" messages (it is not the case in the example above but it can happen in the data). So I need to include also the instances in which the "intruder..." message (but not other messages)appear between the two messages in question.

I would appreciate any tips on how to handle this problem the best way.

Comment: how about using `grep('bad choice', your_data[grep('success', your_data) + 1], value=TRUE)` to check for the line before or after (change to -1) for the success...

Comment: If you don't feel like using a one-liner you don't understand, just loop through your data and when you are on a success, check whether the next one is a bad choice. If it is, increase your counter. This is not an efficient to do this in R but it is the algorithmically straightforward way of doing it and you should be capable of writing it... Use `grep` to check whether a line contains "success" or "bad choice" or "intruder". Honestly, a nice and easy loop with a couple of if's inside is what you should do if you have "no idea" how to deal with this simple problem.

Comment: We can help you correct what you have tried if you show it.

Answer (score 1):

Here with some dummy data... Should give you an idea on your first part of the question.

```
lines <- c("2015-02-20 11:11:02|    134602| end of mat task (passed: 4/5)",
           "2015-02-20 11:11:02|    134599| step E9 abandoned - skipping to next",
           "2015-02-20 11:11:01|    133596| step E9 bad choice - error limit reached",
           "2015-02-20 11:10:38|    110857| step E9 started",
           "2015-02-20 11:10:37|    109844| step E1 success",
           "2015-02-20 11:10:02|     74713| step C12 bad choice")
grep('bad choice', lines[grep('success', lines) + 1], value=TRUE)
```

The second part might be similar, just spread the one line into severals, where you check for your "intruders" and if so, just add or subtract the 1.

As `antoine-sac` suggested in the comments, you can remove the intruders upfront by using

```
tmp <- lines[!grepl(lines, "^intruder.+started$"]
grep('bad choice', tmp[grep('success', tmp) + 1], value=TRUE)
```

Comment: If you just remove the intruders before (with something like `tmp <- lines[!grepl(lines, "^intruder.+started$"]`), your code solves the problem completely when applied on `tmp`.

Comment: Thank you! your solution worked perfectly. @antoine-sac, I removed the intruders as you suggested and it made the whole thing very easy!

Comment: @Ewa: Please consider accepting the solution if it solved your problem (with the big tick at the left of the answer).